# « En comme » (Via Mala, de John Knittel, Albin Michel 1941, p. 315)

Tags: orthographe

> *Via Mala*, de John Knittel
>
> En comme, songeait-il en flanant par les prairies baignées de soleil, Sivvie est comme une de ces montagnes. Il faut escalader glace et neige pour atteindre le sommet.

Je ne trouve pas « en comme » dans les dictionnaires et ça apparait dans la vieille langue, par exemple dans ce [texte](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Nouveau_coutumier_general/7uVBAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22en+comme%22&pg=PA244&printsec=frontcover), mais ça n'a pas de sens.

Je pense plutôt qu'il s'agit d'une erreur typographique et que l'expression est « en somme ».

Quelqu'un pourrait-il confirmer cela (à partir du texte original, par exemple (je n'ai  accès qu'à une édition)) ?

Comment: ça ressemble fort à une coquille, effectivement

Comment: Oui, je ne vois pas autrement.